# Ajax response using json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

so i am sending some query to a php page using java script ajax using data type json. but when the value returning from the php page as json_encode() method i cant show it on the requested page.
here is my code:

```
    var wishlist = {
    'add': function(product_id) {
    // alert(product_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/wishlist.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id +'&type=add',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            var x = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(x);
       });
   },
```

and here is my php page code

```
$pid= $_POST['product_id'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$sql = "select * from category where id = '".$pid."'";
$exe = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe)){
    $value = json_encode($result);
 }
echo $value;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `alert(response)` with `console.log(response)` and observe your browser's console. What you see there, post it in the question.

Comment: @31piy no log in the browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1)

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe)){
    $value = json_encode($result);
 }
echo $value;
```

Unless it so happens that your query only returns one row, this code will give you a problem - every time your `while` loop runs, you'll overwrite `$value` with a totally new value, so you'll only ever see the last line of data returned by your query.

If you know the query will only ever return one row, then the `while` can be replaced with `if`:

```
if($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe)){
    $value = json_encode($result);
 }
echo $value;
```

But if you might return multiple rows, you need to change it to:

```
$values = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe)){
    $values[] = $result;
 }
echo json_encode($values);
```

so that you get a single JSON array containing all the results.

2) `var x = JSON.parse(response);` - due to `dataType: "json"`, `response` is already an object. By setting the `dataType` option as "json" you told jQuery to automatically parse it for you. So you don't need to parse it yourself, therefore this line is redundant.

Doing `alert(response);` probably gets you something meaningless like `[object]` shown in the alert, since `response` is an object, and you can't just display an object as text. You can either stringify it to display the whole object, or pick a specific property to display and alert that, e.g.

Show the whole object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Show a particular attribute:

```
alert(response.id);
```

3) This isn't broken in this case, but I recommend not building your `data` string yourself. It means you don't get the benefit of proper URI-encoding of your data, which jQuery can take care of for you. This means that if you send any characters in your data which have special meaning in a querystring (e.g. `&` or `?`, for example), your string will break and the server won't understand what you've sent it. You won't notice if you're just sending a simple integer or something, but you should get into the habit of doing this so you encounter problems in future.

Instead, give jQuery an object containing the data, and it'll take care of building the querystring for you and encoding it correctly:

```
data: { "product_id" : product_id, "type": "add" },
```

4) This is not directly related to your issue, but it's nonetheless a serious thing which you need to sort out urgently: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.